# Python based network sniffer (scapy not good enough?)

Tags: python, tcp, scapy, packet-sniffers

I am looking for the specific task: 
Grab the payload/data from a packet -> Append to a file... BUT. I want specifically to follow packets according to flags/ICMP types/etc... So lets say I want specifically to take the payload of "echo" packets and not the rest.

My (ineffective) code is the following:

```
from scapy.all import *
f= open('filecaptured', 'a+')
def pkt_diam(pkt):
    raw = pkt.getlayer(Raw).load
    print raw
    # pkt.show()
    # fo = open("payload", "wb")        
    f.write(raw);  
sniff (filter="icmp" , store=0, prn=pkt_diam, timeout = 120 )
```

The problem here is that I cannot find a way to sniff specifically for "type = echo request" and the only parameters that I can use is 'protocol' and host or 'and not host 127.0.0.1'.

Is there a way around this?

I think for this one I need to use ctypes and libpcap.so but I am not sure... (I didnt find any [other] libraries for python - sniffing )

Answer (score 1):

I don't have scapy installed right now, but what if you simply check for the type echo-reply in your callback-function pkt_diam:

```
if not "echo-reply" in pkt.show():
    return
```

Comment: Hi barrios, thanks for your reply... However it looks like it doesnt work :( or maybe I am forgetting something more? :S

if "echo-request" in pkt.show():
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

Try filter="icmp[0]=8" for filtering during capture or

```
if pkt[ICMP].type==8:
```

in callback function.

Comment: Hi Des... This one doesnt work... You can try it for yourself as well. It picks everything :(